# no class def found com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean

Tags: netbeans, java-8, wildfly

I am using `netbeans` as IDE and JAVA 8 with `Wildfly` server.
We need to print total available physical memory of server  for which we are using `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` class (other classes provide memory of runtime) . It compiles fine without any erros but gives no class found error at runtime.
have googled on it and tried the solutions provided but none work.

Comment: `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` is a non-standard extension of `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` that is not guaranteed to be present. You could just ask the manager for the `java.lang.…` variant and check whether the result is implementing `com.sun.…` or check dynamically whether is has the `totalPhysicalMemorySize` property. Of course, if the particular JRE implementation doesn’t provide that feature, there’s no way to get it.

Comment: thanks for the reply , i am also concluding same after searching everywhere